# Matrix differential equation of the form $f'(x)=Ax+b(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose smooth function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies the following matrix differential equation

$$f'(x) = A f(x) + \begin{pmatrix} b(x)\\ 0\\ \vdots\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is some smooth function.

Is there a general method to solve this type of equation explicitly?

Comment: constant coefficient first order linear equation.  The result is $f(x)=\exp(Ax)[f(0)+\int_0^x \exp(-As)b(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\mathbf{e}_1]$

Comment: Formally,   $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-xA}f(x))=e^{-xA}\begin{pmatrix}
b(x)\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for :)!